# Pwershell : Converting multiple HTML data to HTML table

Tags: powershell

I am new powershell. Below is snapshot of my code:

```
$test = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
        
       -----
                    ForEach($list in $runs.steps) 
              {If($list.name ) {
                         ------
                         ----
                          $test.add("$($list.name) - $($Result) - $($Post)")
                        }
              
       
       

}**
```

I want to display list.name , result and Post in to following HTML table format with header "Name", "Result", "Post". Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to construct *objects* with property names corresponding to the table column headers you want:

```
foreach($list in $runs.steps) {
    if($list.name) {
        [void]$test.Add([pscustomobject]@{
            Name = $list.name
            Result = $Result
            Post = $Post
        })
    }
}
```

Now you can construct the desired html table by simply piping the objects to `ConvertTo-Html`:

```
$htmlTableFragment = $test |ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -As Table
```

Comment: Thank you Mathias.  It worked. I was struggling from long time.